# Http: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am developing a nodejs project and bundling it using browserify but im getting this error

```
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

It comes from this line

```
var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)
```

Comment: `http` is a server-side Node module. You can’t use it in a browser if that’s what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Was this solved?

Comment: @Ryan I understand your statement, but in my case it was a problem when I tried to `import express from 'express'`. I did literally nothing more than that and this error appears. Screenshot of Error (The code of interpreted `index.js` is displayed already in the question):
http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/17/0820/h_1503269750_5690631_ef9d0b8db2.png

Comment: @general656: So don’t import it? Again: you can’t use it in a browser.

Comment: Yeah but I actually need the import for requests and responses. I'm seeing people using `express` in their code, why shouldn't I? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They wont work. I am new to nodejs and web development so it took me a while to figure it out. you need to create a server side code and connect the browser side code to it via API calls to get your requests and responses.

Comment: @FatimaHaidar hello, can you please elaborate on this? I'm dealing with the same thing and I'm stuck for hours :( what does it mean to "create a server side code and connect the browser side code to it"? or maybe you have a working example you can share? it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

there is a variable named `http`.
try:

```
var req = Object.create(require('http').IncomingMessage.prototype);
```